No Authorizer is configured error on kafka acl
I want have kafka single node cluster with Kraft mode and also active acl .
just i want acl for use client connection on the my kafka , i do not use acl for internaly kafka connections . but i have No Authorizer is configured error on kafka acl  on the kafka cantainer.
Here is my docker compompose :

version: '3'
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka'
    container_name: kafka
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:2181,CLIENT://0.0.0.0:29092
      -KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@127.0.0.1:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTHORIZER_CLASS=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND=true
      - KAFKA_SUPER_USERS=User:admin
      - KAFKA_JAAS_CONFIG=file:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/kafka_jaas.conf
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN ##
      - KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.apache.kafka=DEBUG,org.apache.zookeeper=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - ./kafka:/opt/bitnami/


Please show the exact error and the command you're using to get it. If you want to enforce ACLs, you probably don't want KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND=true

Here is my error(i want active acl for client i do not use acl for use internally connection ) :          (
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured.

When do you get this error? I see you have KAFKA_CFG_AUTHORIZER_CLASS set, so maybe this isn't being used?

i do now know , when do not use this "KAFKA_CFG_AUTHORIZER_CLASS" i have this error : KAFKA_CFG_AUTHORIZER_CLASS , but doese not claer active acl from client side for kafka for docker-compose .

You've still not specified what commands you're running to get this error. Please [edit] your question to include logs or code

kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server 10.1.16.33:9092 
--command-config /opt/bitnami/kafka/config/client.properties 
--add --allow-principal User:admin 
--operation All --resource-pattern-type LITERAL 
--cluster

Again, please [edit] your question to include additional details rather than using comments
